# Why is my POST request not reaching my Sails server in a Docker virtual machine?

Tags: reactjs, docker, sails.js, http-status-code-404

We have a full-stack app running with a React front-end UI and a Node-based Sails API and Postgres database on the backend. The backend is set to run on a Docker virtual machine. So here's the problem: the UI is up and running fine as is the Docker server and VM as far as we can tell. However, our user login functionality has stopped connecting with our server for some reason. The POST request that is supposed to create a user returns a 404 Not Found error, never actually hitting the /users/create endpoint as it should.

We have tried completely reinstalling docker and the virtual machine, clearing out the cache and starting from scratch. The error does not change. We have also compared the code of the machines that are receiving this error with a computer that is NOT receiving the error and there is no difference in the actual server, endpoint or docker files.

Potentially worth mentioning is that our Sails server in Docker is not able to find and run our grunt file, which it used to be doing (and is still on one computer). But that file isn't doing anything directly related to the server and shouldn't be causing the 404 we don't think so it's probably not relevant.

Another problem is that prior to installing a CORS Chrome Extension that allows same origin requests, we were just getting a CORS error that prevented the request from even going off. The extension seems to have fixed this for now and this is likely also not related, but maybe worth mentioning anyways.

This is our create user JavaScript (React) function in our user reducer.

```
    export const registrationEpic = action$ =>
      action$.ofType(USER_REGISTRATION)
        .mergeMap(action => ajax.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users/create`, action.payload)
          .map(data => {
            let response = data.response;
            if (response.user && response.token) {
              return userRegistrationFulfilled();
            } else {
              return Observable.of(userRegistrationRejected(["Unknown error. Please, refresh page and try again."]));
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            let errors = sailsErrors.parseValidationErrors(error.response);
            return Observable.of(userRegistrationRejected(!!errors ? errors : ["Unknown error. Please, refresh page and try again."]))
          }));
```

I don't think this code is particularly relevant, though -- this functionality seems fine and was previously working. The problem seems to be in the Sails server - Docker connection which isn't "visible".

I expect that when users enter their information, they will be logged in via the create endpoint of our server (like it used to work). Now, the data is being submitted, but the console is just returning a 404 not found error on the create endpoint of our Sails server.

Comment: When you `console.log(\`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users/create\`)`, do you get the expected API url? If it is the case, have you tested it using curl?

Comment: @PierreV. yes, that returns the correct URL and port. When we run it through Postman, the result is the same. It connects correctly but returns a 404 like in the browser.

Comment: Nice I like the rxjs. It would be awesome to share how you guys got react into it. I wrote an article on medium about it, but I'm curious to see how others do it. I also did SSR but am looking at how others do it, to perfect it.